# База данных sqlite3

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, sqlite3

мне нужно подключить базу данных для команд как mute ban (ban у меня настроен как mute) но не знаю как, подскажите пожалуйста, вот коды mute'a и ban'a

````
@bot.command(pass_context = True, aliases=['размут'])
@commands.has_permissions(manage_nicknames=True)
async def unmute(ctx, *, member: discord.Member):
    channel = bot.get_channel(1003020078054391899)
    mute_role = discord.utils.get(ctx.message.guild.roles, name = 'Muted')
    await member.remove_roles(mute_role)
    embed = discord.Embed(title=f'{member} был размучен \nМодератор: {ctx.author}', timestamp=datetime.datetime.utcnow())
    await channel.send(embed=embed)
    await ctx.message.delete()

@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_nicknames=True)
async def mute(ctx, user: discord.Member, time: int, *, reason=None):
    channel = bot.get_channel(1003020078054391899)
    if reason==None:
        reason="Причина не указана"
    role = user.guild.get_role(1004036469716942948) # айди роли которую будет получать юзер
    embed = discord.Embed(title=f'{user} получил мут на {time} минут по причине:', description=f"**```\n{reason}\n``` .\nМодератор: {ctx.author}**", timestamp=datetime.datetime.utcnow())
    await channel.send(embed=embed)
    await ctx.message.delete()
    await user.add_roles(role)
    await user.move_to(None)
    await asyncio.sleep(time * 60)
    await user.remove_roles(role)
    
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def ban(ctx, user: discord.Member, time: int, *, reason=None):
    channel = bot.get_channel(1003020078054391899)
    if reason==None:
        reason="Причина не указана"
    role = user.guild.get_role(1003667969919946803) # айди роли которую будет получать юзер
    embed = discord.Embed(title=f'{user} получил бан на {time} дней по причине: ', description=f'**```\n{reason}\n``` Модератор: {ctx.author}**', timestamp=datetime.datetime.utcnow())
    await channel.send(embed=embed)
    await ctx.message.delete()
    await user.add_roles(role)
    await user.move_to(None)
    await asyncio.sleep(time * 86400)
    await user.remove_roles(role)
    
@bot.command(pass_context = True, aliases=['разбан'])
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def unban(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    channel = bot.get_channel(1003020078054391899)
    ban_role = discord.utils.get(ctx.message.guild.roles, name = 'Banned')
    await member.remove_roles(ban_role)
    embed = discord.Embed(title=f'{member} был разбанен.\nМодератор: {ctx.author}', timestamp=datetime.datetime.utcnow())
    await channel.send(embed=embed)
    await ctx.message.delete()
````

так же тут unban и unmute

Comment: курсоры не подключены

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам для начала нужно создать таблицу. Для этого можете воспользоваться [создателем таблиц для sqlite](https://sqlitebrowser.org)(интерфейс интуитивно понятен), либо создать через код(гайдов на это куча).
**Отрывок брал со своего бота**. Если будут вопросы - помогу чем смогу

```
import discord
import sqlite3
from discord.ext import commands 

#в теле бота мы подключаем ДБшку, которую создали через DB BROWSER

db = sqlite3.connect('database/base.sqlite') #подключаем таблицу, которая должна лежать в пути bot/название папки с таблицей
cursor = db.cursor()
```

Далее вам нужно подключить таблицу в ивентах @on_ready(бот будет заносить в таблицу новых участников при включении) и в @on_join(добавлять юзера при заходе на сервер)

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready(): #Циклы для перебора участников серверов на котором находится бот
    for guild in bot.guilds:
        for member in guild.members:
            if cursor.execute(f"SELECT member_id FROM main WHERE member_id = {member.id}").fetchone() is None:
                cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO main VALUES (?, ?, 0, 500, 0, 1)", (str(member), member.id)) #защита от кражи данных, в "?" подставляются значения
                db.commit() #применение данных в базе
            else:
                pass #если участник уже записан - повторной записи на одного участника не будет

    print('Бот запущен')

@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
   cursor.execute(f"SELECT member_id FROM main WHERE member_id = '{member.id}'")
   if cursor.fetchone() is None:
       cursor.execute("INSERT INTO main VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);", (member, member.id, 0, 500, 0, 1))
       db.commit()
   else:
       pass
```

После этих этапов можно подключать уже в команды

```
@bot.command(pass_context = True, aliases=['размут'])
@commands.has_permissions(manage_nicknames=True)
async def unmute(ctx, *, member: discord.Member):

    db = sqlite3.connect("Путь к таблице")
    cursor = db.cursor()
    
    #Далее по созданным типам данных и названий в таблице укажите запрос, ссылку оставлю ниже.
    
    channel = bot.get_channel(1003020078054391899)
    mute_role = discord.utils.get(ctx.message.guild.roles, name = 'Muted')
    await member.remove_roles(mute_role)
    embed = discord.Embed(title=f'{member} был размучен \nМодератор: {ctx.author}', timestamp=datetime.datetime.utcnow())
    await channel.send(embed=embed)
    await ctx.message.delete()
```

[пример запросов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1437491/discord-py-sqlite3-%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%8B-work)

Comment: спасибо большое