# Discord.py + SQLite3. Подскажите пожалуйста по поводу команды work

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, sqlite3

Сложность возникла с выводом баланса пользователя и сложения его с заработанными деньгами. Подскажите пожалуйста

````
@client.command(aleases=["work"])
        async def work(ctx):
            works = ["грузчиком", "копирайтером", "доставщиком", "водителем", "дворником"]

            cash = random.randrange(25, 180)

            db = sqlite3.connect("database/economy.sqlite")
            cursor = db.cursor()
            cursor.execute(f"SELECT wallet From main WHERE member_id = {ctx.author.id}")
            cursor.execute(f"UPDATE main SET wallet == ? WHERE member_id".format(cash, ctx.author.id))
            db.commit()

            embed = discord.Embed(colour=get_rand_color(), timestamp=ctx.message.created_at)
            embed.set_author(name=f"{ctx.author} устроился на подработку {random.choice(works)}", icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
            embed.add_field(name="Заработал:", value=f"{cash}")
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте задать выбор баланса в переменную так-же добавив .fetchone() в конце (фетчван выбирает один элемент)

```
wallet = cursor.execute(f"SELECT wallet FROM main WHERE member_id = {ctx.author.id}").fetchone()
```